# Communication between user process, terminal and kernel

Tags: linux, process, terminal, kernel

A user process communicates to terminal using 3 file descriptors. The terminal is regarded as file in unix (for example `/dev/tty`) and also has file descriptor, major, minor number for kernel to identify it. So the kernel communicates with the user process through the terminal. Another way to communicate is through system calls that we all know.

Suppose the user process is waiting for input (example: `enter two numbers: _ _`). When we press <kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>2</kbd> on the keyboard, the keyboard buffer is filled, the device driver associated with the keyboard will identify it and will wake the process in its wait queue. So how is this data (i.e `1` and `2`) made avaliable to the user process? It will be through terminal I guess.

Also what happens if redirect the output, e.g `$ ./a.out > file`? I have checked using `isatty()` that the process is not associated with any terminal. Then how will the kernel interact with the user process? Suppose my programm requires some input from keyboard.

Comment: The terminal itself is treated specially by the kernel.  There are process groups and the foreground process for the group gets console input.  You can use things like [screen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) to give several programs the foreground.  Besides the nature of a terminal, I don't see what your question is about that does not have many duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

When your program calls an input function, for example:

```
nread = read(FILENO_STDIN, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

a "system call" is made into the kernel.  This kernel routine makes sure the buffer you passed to it is in your program's address space and then copies the characters (no more than the size you passed in) from the terminal device's kernel buffer into the buffer you supplied and returns to you the count of those.

A very similar thing happens if the file descriptor (arg 1) points at an open file -- the data comes from the file system's kernel buffer (possibly it needs to be copied from the actual device to there first).

Comment: i m not using any read function i my user process. i wanted to know how the data from keyboard buffer  is coming from to user process through terminal . i m using scanf in my program.  
i have seen somewhere that scanf is in turn calling read function. then how are arguments of read function mapped with scanf. buffer address could be address of variable(i.e &x) but what about size arguments in read function ? how it will be calculated.

Comment: also if kernel is copying keyboard buffer data directly to user space then how come the data is appearing on the terminal. 
for example: enter two integers: _ _  . when i give input it should not appear on the terminal , instead it should directly be copied to variable address(which is in user space) . i wanted to know how data is displayed on the terminal as well as copied to user space variable address . Plz don't ignore the terminal part. i want to know the mechanism. 
thank you

Comment: @debendranathtiwary `scanf()` doesn't call `read()` fucntion internally.

Comment: @debendranathtiwary If you are calling `scanf()` somewhere along the line the `read()` function is getting called to transfer data from the kernel's terminal buffer into the user-space buffer.  The stdio input functions are buffered, so when the buffer is empty, a typical strategy is to issue a read giving the full size of the buffer, then future "reads" can be satisfied by just copying one or more characters out of the buffer and adjusting the count of bytes available in the buffer.  The constant `BUFSIZ` gives you the nominal size of this buffer.

Comment: @JohnHascall thank you. ok, is there only 1 buffer for input , output and output stream. as per i know output stream is not associated with any buffer. please correct me if i m wrong. also , how can i directly access those buffers.

Answer (score 0):

The high level answer to your question is that the  you have

```
User process <> Kernel <> Terminal Driver
```

In some systems the terminal driver may be part of the kernel. On others it is separate code executed in kernel mode (fine distinction).

When someone presses a key, it triggers system interrupt that gets handled by the driver. Here, one of two things can happen, depending upon how the kernel has told the driver to behave or how the driver is implemented.

1) The driver may simply store the keystroke in a buffer; or
2) The driver may notify the kernel each time it gets a keystroke.

The kernel may interact with the process in a number of ways, depending upon the system and how the process has configured the terminal:

1) The kernel may do nothing with the data from the terminal until the process calls for it. The process supplies a buffer, the kernel copies the data from its internal buffer (or the driver's buffer).
2) The kernel may send a software interrupt to the process (e.g., Windows or VMS). In this case the process will have supplied a buffer to the kernel beforehand for its to copy the data to.
3) The kernel may queue an event to the process that the process will have to query.

In regard your section question, redirection is managed entirely outside the kernel. An application (usually a command line shell) usually interprets this

```
  ./a.out > file
```

by

```
1) Open FILE.
2) Create a new process where the standard output is the handle to FILE.
3) Run a.out in that process.
```

Comment: thanks . 
./a.out > file is not asociated with the terminal (as isatty fails)
but 
./a.out < file is associated with the terminal (as isatty succeds)
how come this different behaviour.